# Защита некоторых данных от декомпиляции

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, защита, декомпиляция

Есть метод, который заливает некоторые файлы на FTP сервер. В этот метод передаются 2 string - логин и пароль от FTP. Читал, что особого смысла в защите кода .Net нет, ибо он очень легко декомпилируется. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно обезопасить именно какие-то конкретные данные, типа логина и пароля.

Comment: Декомпиляцию можно сделать *исполнимому* коду (dll,exe). До тех пор пока нету доступа к папке с dll или exe - ваш код декомпилировать не получится.

Comment: Ну а если это простая программа, состоящая из одного исполняемого файла .exe?

Comment: Стройте архитектуру приложения таким образом, чтобы логин и пароль от FTP не были секретными для пользователя - тогда и защищать их будет не нужно.

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, как можно в exe-шнике поставить защиту от чтения вашего логина пароля?  Так это безполезно, т.к. вашу програму декомпилировать не нужно. Легче взять любой снифер и подглянуть протокол)))

Comment: @free_ze: А почему удалили?

Comment: @VladD Поднял глаза на комментарии. Хотя...вы правы, ответы должны быть в ответах

Comment: @free_ze: Как раз недавно на Мете была [дискуссия по этому поводу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/10105).

Comment: А почему просто не использовать авторизацию через API к примеру вк?

Comment: @ZederBreys как вариант, но тогда и сервер придётся пилить под авторизацию вк

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Защищать C#-программу нет смысла, т.к. FTP подразумевает передачу данных в открытом виде. Достаточно будет сниффера.

Comment: Ответ спорный, ведь можно использовать "временные" пароли. Реализовать "единоразовые" пароли входа, например даже рандомные. Правда да, это защита от подглядывания пароля а не от декомпиляции.

Comment: @nick_n_a Можно и троллейбус из хлеба сделать. Как будут синхронизироваться базы рандомных паролей между сервером и клиентом?

Comment: Через хеш. Хеш сума пароля должна совпасть, а алгоритм хеша - знает сервер и клиент. Чем сложнее алгоритм - тем сложнее его декомпилировать.

Comment: @nick_n_a Клиент будет брутфорсить свой сервер в поисках неиспользованного пароля?) Даже если так, что мешает перехватывать запросы и изменять его под свои нужды?

Comment: @free_ze, например FTPS вместо FTP. Я думаю это будет разумнее, хотя тоже не панацея. Хотите секьюрности - пишите свой клиент и сервер)

Comment: @Alexis Вы на что отвечаете?)

Comment: @free_ze, частично на это: "Даже если так, что мешает перехватывать запросы и изменять его под свои нужды?" и частично на вопрос ТС.

Comment: @Alexis У нас тут речь про FTP и адские велосипеды аутентификации)

Comment: @free_ze, я не претендую на ответ или еще что-то. Просто хотел добавить инфы ТС-у. Может он и не знает об FTPS...