# C# защита от декомпиляции

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Интересуюсь одним довольно важным вопросом.
Как защитить C# WinForms приложение от декомпиляции, при том, чтобы приложение не считалось вирусом?
Когда накладываешь обфускацию например, то virustotal сразу же орёт что это вирус. А хотелось бы защитить приложение от декомпиляции и остаться невидимым для антивируса.

Comment: Не как, C# - открытый язык. Хотите закрытости, то вам явно стоит менять то, на чем вы пишете.

Comment: Пару раз пользовался .NET Reactor, но вот насколько это эффективно, как влияет на производительность хз. Хотя бы dotPeek не показывал исходники, только сигнатуры ф-ий )

Comment: А так секреты не стоит держать в приложении самом. Для этого существуют сторонние сервисы к которым нужен доступ и прочее

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529499) от меня был, но суть одна - .NET приложения от декомпиляции не защитить.

Comment: @Jagailo ну так время [не стоит на месте](https://github.com/dotnet/corert)

Comment: Можно ваш абсолютно уникальный ТМ-код вынести в библиотеку на Си ее подключить через Pinvoke, например проверку ключей защиты, или какой-нибудь важный функционал, тогда ваш код на .NET будет сложнее повторить. Декомпиляция конечно ускорит клонирование вашего кода, но и без нее все можно сделать это вопрос цены. Биос от IBM тому был примером, его алгоритм повторили люди ни разу не видевшие его исходного кода.

Answer (score 1):

Свободный перевод ответа [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515884/how-to-convert-c-sharp-to-dll-to-hide-the-source-code)

> I believe you are looking for an obfuscator. This is a tool that will
> take a compiled DLL and rewrite the code with the intent of it not
> being meaningfully decompiled by another user. Visual Studio comes
> with a free Dotfuscator
>
> Note, this will not actually prevent people from looking at your code.
> They will instead be looking at a very weird translation of your code.
> There is no way to prevent people from looking at decompiled versions
> of your code in C# or any other .Net language for that matter.
>
> This is not something that is unique to C#. It is fact a flaw of every
> language in existence. It's perfectly possible to decompile C code.
> The difference though is it's much easier to maintain a lot of the
> original code structure when decompiling managed languages (.Net and
> Java for instance) because the metadata maintains the original
> structure.

Я считаю, что вы ищете обфускатор. Это инструмент, который берет скомпилированную DLL и переписывает код с намерением, чтобы он не декомпилировался другим пользователем. Visual Studio поставляется с бесплатным Dotfuscator

Обратите внимание: это не помешает людям взглянуть на ваш код. Вместо этого они будут смотреть на очень странный перевод вашего кода. Невозможно запретить людям просматривать декомпилированные версии вашего кода на C # или любом другом языке .Net в этом отношении.

Это не является чем-то уникальным для C#. На самом деле это недостаток любого существующего языка. Декомпилировать C#- код вполне возможно. Разница, однако, в том, что при декомпиляции управляемых языков (например, .Net и Java) намного проще сохранить большую часть исходной структуры кода, поскольку метаданные поддерживают исходную структуру.